# More than one state property change in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I was using redux to check how it scales with my application. There are few things, that I found as roadblock when I was using it. 
There are high possibility that I am not thinking the redux way / not using the way it was supposed to be used or have not read the doc properly.
I have read the basic section [this docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html).

The problem statement is fairly simple.
I have two property in store

```
{
    x: 10, 
    y: 20
}
```

lets say `x` is the x-position of the point and `y` is the y-position of the point. There is one condition if the x goes above 50, y value becomes equal to x.

So I have this

```
let x = (state = 10, action ) => {
    if (action.type === 'cx') {
        return action.value;
    }
    else {
        return state;
    }
}

let y = (state = 20, action ) => {
    if (action.type === 'cy') {
        return action.value;
    }
    else {
        return state;
    }
}

let model = redux.combineReducers({x: x, y: y});
let store = redux.createStore(model);

let actions = {
    changeX: (val) => {
        if ( val > 50) {
            store.dispatch(actions.changeY(val));
        }
        return {type: 'cx', value: val }
    },
    changeY: (val) => ({type: 'cy', value: val })
}

console.log('INITIAL STATE', '---', store.getState());

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('SUB2', '---', store.getState());
    // Paint the dom with new state
});
```

So the moment

```
store.dispatch(actions.changeX(60));
```

is called the subscriber's function gets called twice hence the two times dom painting happen.

Is there a redux-way / workaround to solve this?

Comment: It sounds like you should be managing both x and y in a single reducer, as they're not independent.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thats one probable solution. But in my case the actions to change x and y are unpredictable. Sometime  my components might change X and  Y independently. If I have to handle this in one common reducer then I have to keep track of the state inside reducer.

Comment: It sounds like you have two state variables (x/y) and two actions to handle (changeX/changeY).  If changeX occurs, your reducer updates both x and y.  If changeY occurs, your reducer updates only y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to relate to `x` and `y` as part of the same sub model equation - when one is updated, the other maybe updated also.

Using [combineReducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) you can update related state in the same reducer.

According to [Redux guide](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html), if you want that states to be separated, sometimes `combineReducer` is not enough, and you can [breach that pattern into more openly reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers).

> The combineReducers utility included with Redux is very useful, but is
>   deliberately limited to handle a single common use case: updating a
>   state tree that is a plain Javascript object, by delegating the work
>   of updating each slice of state to a specific slice reducer. It does
>   not handle other use cases, such as a state tree made up of
>   Immutable.js Maps, trying to pass other portions of the state tree as
>   an additional argument to a slice reducer, or performing "ordering" of
>   slice reducer calls. It also does not care how a given slice reducer
>   does its work.
>
> The common question, then, is "How can I use combineReducers to handle
>   these other use cases?". The answer to that is simply: "you don't -
>   you probably need to use something else". Once you go past the core
>   use case for combineReducers, it's time to use more "custom" reducer
>   logic, whether it be specific logic for a one-off use case, or a
>   reusable function that could be widely shared. Here's some suggestions
>   for dealing with a couple of these typical use cases, but feel free to
>   come up with your own approaches.

An example that is given related for this case:

```
function combinedReducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "A_TYPICAL_ACTION" : {
            return {
                a : sliceReducerA(state.a, action),
                b : sliceReducerB(state.b, action)
            };
        }
        case "SOME_SPECIAL_ACTION" : {
            return {
                // specifically pass state.b as an additional argument
                a : sliceReducerA(state.a, action, state.b),
                b : sliceReducerB(state.b, action)
            }        
        }
        case "ANOTHER_SPECIAL_ACTION" : {
            return {
                a : sliceReducerA(state.a, action),
                // specifically pass the entire state as an additional argument
                b : sliceReducerB(state.b, action, state)
            }         
        }    
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Combining reducers seems like overkill here - it feels like `case "CHANGE_X": return { x: action.value; y: action.value > 50 ? action.value : state.y; } case "CHANGE_Y": return { x: state.x, y: action.value }` would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes. I giving another option apart from your answer. I do agree that in that case, x and y are related conceptually and can be put in the same model reducer.